# Colocar legenda Display="block" ao passar por cima da imagem e ao retirar Display="none"

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Quero fazer um efeito com o JavaScript, ao passar o mouse em cima da imagem é preciso que apareça a legenda e ao retirar o mouse quero que a mesma fique oculta. No entanto, não consigo chegar ao resultado desejado. Já coloquei os eventos dentro da div, porém o que fica oculto quando retiro o mouse é a imagem e não a legenda.

```js
function descricao(){
 document.getElementById("sublime").style.display='block';
}

function retira(){
 document.getElementById("sublime").style.display='none';
}
```

```css
#sublime{
 opacity: 1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 382px;
 background-image: url(imagens/sublime.png);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

#sublime:hover{
 opacity: 0.5;
 transition: 1s;
}

#sublime p {
 font-size: 100px;
 color: black;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
 .corpo2{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .corpo2 h3{
  margin-left: 13%;
 }

 #sublime{
  width: 330px;
  height: 191px;
  background-image: url(imagens/sublime2.png);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="sublime">
  <p style="display: none" onmouseover="descricao()"      onmouseout="retira()">Sublime Net, projeto de Tecnologia de negócios na internet. joaovitorleffa.github.io</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer com javascript, pode usar o atributo title na imagem:

```
<img src="sublime2.png"  title="Sublime Net, projeto de Tecnologia de negócios na internet. joaovitorleffa.github.io"/>
```

E você pode usar o title em outras coisas também: `<div>, <input>, <a>`...